# Proving a set of circles to be belonging to a family of circles.

Tags: triangles, circles

**Question:**

> Given a $\triangle ABC$, a pair of congruent circles are drawn(one pair at a time, in the figure colored Red,Orange,Blue) by taking $B,C$ as centers. They cut sides $BC,AC$ at pair of points $($in fig. $(D,G);(E,H);(F,I)$$)$.
>   Now taking those pair of points and $A$ as vertices of triangles, circumcircles are drawn(in the fig. green colored.) Prove that they all pass through a common point which is $(X$ in the figure$)$

**Figure:**
[image]

The question was long, I solved it till here(where I'm stuck.)
Thanks for sparing time to view my question and providing hints,solutions.

Comment: I do not see anything *solved*, just drawn. Anyway, did you figure what $X$ has to be? I claim the midpoint of the major $BC$-arc in the circumcircle of $ABC$. What do you get by applying angle chasing and symmetry?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio- The question was very long though. Omitted other part. Just this part is left. I didn't claim $X$ to be anything. Let me check what you say and try. What you say is true indeed, I know that. I was trying coordinate geometry though. The reason why I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U,V$ be points on $BA,CA$ such that $BU=CV$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and let $X$ be the midpoint of the major $BC$-arc in the circumcircle of $ABC$.

My claim is that $A,U,V,X$ belong to the same circle, i.e. $\widehat{UXV}=\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{A}$.

[image]

It is simple to notice that $\widehat{UBX}=\widehat{VCX}$, hence $UBX=VCX$ by SAS.
Indeed $\widehat{XBC}=\widehat{XCB}=\frac{\pi-\widehat{A}}{2}$ and 
$$ \widehat{UBX}=\widehat{B}-\frac{\pi-\widehat{A}}{2} = \frac{\pi-\widehat{A}}{2}-\widehat{C}=\widehat{VCX}.$$
This gives
$$ \widehat{UXV}=\widehat{BXC}=\widehat{A}$$
as wanted.

Comment: I think it's a lame question but what does  the symbol $\widehat {UXV}$ mean. Do you mean by arc??

Comment: @LoveInvariants: $\widehat{UXV}$ is the angle at $X$ in the triangle $UXV$. For brevity, $\widehat{A},\widehat{B},\widehat{C}$ denote the angles of $ABC$.

Comment: Oh I'm used to $\angle UXV$

Comment: How do you notice that simple thing? I mean how $\angle UBX=\angle VCX$?

Comment: @LoveInvariants: it is explained *how*. I noticed a striking resemblance between the shapes of the purple triangles.

Comment: Didn't read the next line. I stopped there. Thanks btw for solution.